# How do I group these binomial sample estimates?

Tags: estimation, sampling, binomial-distribution, sample-size

Take a look at this sample data, by age of participants (which hopefully I computed correctly):

[image: Binomial Sample by Age]

Now, I would like to give the numbers for the Age Range (40-44), so I tried Simply summing the trials and success and computing from there:
[image: Totals]

But, it seems odd to me that the Std deviation would be smaller, given we have spread out data. I mean, a random person from age group 40-44 is going to be one of the actual ages 40,41,42,43,44 at random. So, it seems like a 99% CI would encompass a broader range of values for an age-group than an age.

Am I just wrong about that, or do I need another approach? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we aggregate the data to get a single estimate as you have done, it is tacitly being assumed that every part of that data arose from the same data generating mechanism.

With more "i.i.d." data we have a more precise estimate of the mean, which should not be surprising. However, it does not appear that the success rate is equal for all ages within the rage 40-44.

Comment: Thanks. It's being assumed that there is some correlation between age and success rate. I would rather like to "group" these results more so than combine them into a single experiment, as there will be other groups from higher ages to compare to. Can I take the 5 sets of results, and average those together with N=5 to get the numbers for the group, or is that the wrong way to go? It seems to me that the CI of the group should be lower than the lowest mean from of the subset and higher than the highest. How would you do it? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: There is no particular reason why the CI should be lower than the lowest mean. The CI pertains to the mean of the pooled population which will be sort of a weighted average of the means of the individual ages. I think it is fine to group the ages as you want to do. My preference would be to try to fit a model relating probability of success to age.